# How to use AppBaseActivity and ActionBarActivity both in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I'm using a theme i.e Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar in my application so that i can get an action bar in my main activity.For this i must extends my MainActivity with ActionBarActivity.And also to register or unregister my activity i had created one separate class AppBaseActivity so that i can close my activity completely at the time of logout.
My question is as Java doesn't support Multiple inheritance how can we use these both classes in my MainActivity.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make AppBaseActivity extends ActionbarActivity and then make YourActivity extends AppBaseActivity. It will take advantage of both AppBaseActivity and ActionbarActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multilevel inheritance instead.

Extend your `AppBaseActivity` say base activity with `ActionBarActivity` and then extend your other activity with `AppBaseActivity`. I believe it will do the trick for you.